# How to send an array using requests.post (Python)? "Value Error: Too many values to unpack"

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to send an array(list) of requests to the WheniWork API using requests.post, and I keep getting one of two errors. When I send the list as a list, I get an unpacking error, and when I send it as a string, I get an error asking me to submit an array. I think it has something to do with how requests handles lists. Here are the examples:

```
url='https://api.wheniwork.com/2/batch'
headers={"W-Token": "Ilovemyboss"}
data=[{'url': '/rest/shifts', 'params': {'user_id': 0,'other_stuff':'value'}, 'method':'post',{'url': '/rest/shifts', 'params': {'user_id': 1,'other_stuff':'value'}, 'method':'post'}]
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers,data=data)
print r.text

# ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Simply wrapping the value for data in quotes:

```
url='https://api.wheniwork.com/2/batch'
headers={"W-Token": "Ilovemyboss"}
data="[]" #removed the data here to emphasize that the only change is the quotes
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers,data=data)
print r.text

#{"error":"Please include an array of requests to make.","code":5000}
```

Answer (score 143):

You want to pass in *JSON encoded* data. See the [API documentation](http://dev.wheniwork.com/):

> Remember — All post bodies must be JSON encoded data (no form data).

The `requests` library makes this trivially easy:

```
headers = {"W-Token": "Ilovemyboss"}
data = [
    {
        'url': '/rest/shifts',
        'params': {'user_id': 0, 'other_stuff': 'value'},
        'method': 'post',
    },
    {
        'url': '/rest/shifts',
        'params': {'user_id': 1,'other_stuff': 'value'},
        'method':'post',
    },
]
requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
```

By using the `json` keyword argument the data is encoded to JSON for you, and the `Content-Type` header is set to `application/json`.

Comment: causing less trouble than data=json.dumps(payload). Thanks for solution.

Answer (score 39):

Well, It turns out that all I needed to do was add these headers:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept':'application/json'}
```

and then call requests

```
requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

and now i'm good!

Answer (score 13):

Always remember when sending an *array(list)* or *dictionary* in the ***HTTP POST*** request, do use **json argument** in the post function and set its value to your **array(list)/dictionary**.

In your case it will be like:

> r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)

**Note:** *POST requests implicitly convert parameter's content type for body to application/json.*

For a quick intro read [API-Integration-In-Python](https://realpython.com/api-integration-in-python/)

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar case but totally different solution,
I've copied a snippet of code which looks like that:

```
resp_status, resp_data = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload, verify=False)
```

and this resulted in error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

just assigning to one variable resolve the issue:

```
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload, verify=False)
```