# How to send the data of the request in the right format?

Tags: python, http, post, python-requests

I want to login into a website but I sent the data of the post request like this:['username', 'password'] but the server will accept only using a double quote, like this["username", "password"].

I tried to send the request like this:

```
postdata = [username, password]
resp = requests.post(SERVER_IP, data=str(postdata).encode(), headers=my_headers)
```

I need to change it that it will send the user name and password with " and not '

Comment: str(postdata).replace('\'', '\"')? But that's kinda strange data format at the first place

Comment: I did like you showed and it looks like this in Wireshark: b"["username", "password"]"

Comment: Everything depends on the server here. Can it accept json? if yes, this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31168819/how-to-send-an-array-using-requests-post-python-value-error-too-many-values

Comment: No, when I log in in the website manually  it send the data exactly as I showed: ["username","password"]

Comment: You could try to send data in json format anyway, not in plain string, providing correct Content-Type header, like it described in answer above. Json should be fine, and you describe exactly array in json format (yep, it's not dict, but still valid json)

Comment: you could add URL for this website so we could see this problem in browser.

Comment: what do you get when you request as `json=postdata` instead of data